# ffmpeg - how to set histogram size?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add a histogram to a video using ffmpeg, I'm following [this example](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FancyFilteringExamples#waveform), but I'm having trouble setting the size of the histogram, this is the code I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -y -report -i input.mp4 -vf "split[a][b];[a]format=gray,histogram=mode=waveform:waveform_mode=column,vflip,split[c][d];[b]pad=iw:ih+256[padded];[c]geq=g=1:b=1[red];[d]geq=r=1:b=1,crop=in_w:220:0:16[mid];[red][mid]overlay=0:16[wave];[padded][wave]overlay=0:H-h"  output.mp4
```

I've tried to play around with the `pad` and `crop` values without luck.
How can I set the size of histogram to 100 pixels only?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem adding a scale value:

```
scale=1280:100
```

`1280` being the width and `100` the height (output video is 1280x720)

The final code looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -report -i input.mp4 -vf "split[a][b];[a]format=gray,histogram=mode=waveform:waveform_mode=column,vflip,scale=1280:100,split[c][d];[b]pad=iw:ih+256[padded];[c]geq=g=1:b=1[red];[d]geq=r=1:b=1,crop=in_w:220:0:16[mid];[red][mid]overlay=0:16[wave];[padded][wave]overlay=0:H-h"  output.mp4
```